# Upload a document in a specific folder

Tags: javascript, custom-form, file-upload

I would like to set a specific folder when I open the upload.aspx page to help.
I tryed to look in the dll but the license of reflector is expired.

**UPDATED**

Maybe this post can help: [How to set the destination folder in OOB Upload page!](http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.it/2012/11/how-to-set-destination-folder-in-oob.html)

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Comment to your statement about reflector: You could try [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) by JetBrains <3. I usually just use ReSharper, then I can right click or _ctrl+b_ and get the code decompiled directly.

Comment: @rjcup3 I try to upload a file by the oob upload.aspx dialog and I would like to set in which folder upload the file

Comment: @eirikb I will try it :)

Comment: I did some reverse engineer to set the RootFolder information but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

have you tried by creating a new upload link by using the root folder parameter in query string.

example

```
https://sharepoint.contoso.com/sites/YourSiteUrl/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={Destination LIST GUID}&RootFolder="ServerRelativeURL of destination folder"
```

Answer (score 0):

create an webpart with the upload control and set the path as you want, edit upload.aspx - hide the actual content and insert your webpart, otherwise a nasty workaround - let the upload operation go as it is presently, create an event receiver and move the file while adding the file on ItemAdding event

Comment: Ok it's the long way but I see the UploadPage code behind use a RootFolder variable to works.

Comment: As far as I know the root folder attribute as completely different thing that you expected, it's mainly used as redirecturl i.e. after uploading the file the page will be redirected to some other page (generally the document library all items page), rootfolder is used for that purpose, anyway u hv not mentioned one important thing, are you using SP2007, SP2010 or SP2013?

Comment: I made a solution. I will write a post about it.